# Convert std::string from one locale to another one

Tags: c++, string, character-encoding, localization, locale

How to convert `std::string` of one locale to another?
For example, I have `std::string` in `std::locale("ru_RU.koi8r")` and what to create a `std::string` in `std::locale("ru_RU.CP1251")` or to `std::locale("zh_CN.gb18030")`, or whatever.

Comment: [`std::codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) should be your friend.

Comment: Please show how to implement my example with `std::codecvt`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm very unfamiliar with it. The only thing I know is that you can do charset conversion with it. Maybe the example in [`std::codecvt::in`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt/in) helps...

Comment: `codecvt` might be your friend, if the version of the standard library you are building against supports it well. GCC does not, as of time of writing, Clang does and I think MSVC probably does (at least partially).

Comment: You may find it more reliable and portable to use a heavyweight unicode library like ICU or libiconv.

Comment: I am interesting is it possible to do that with codecvt (or any other std facility), because from the reference it is written "conversion of character strings, including wide and multibyte, from one encoding to another". But looking at all the methods and examples there, I have not found any clue how to make "conversion ... from one encoding to another". It is very confusing. Yes, @Rook I know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `codecvt` is the right answer for this kind of problems.

## Introduction to codecvt:

The goal of `codecvt<internal, external, state>` facet is to provide on the flow character encoding conversions between the internal representation (variables in memory) and the stream representation (data on file):

- the codecvt to be used for a stream, if any, is defined in its locale with `imbue()`.
- when reading data from a stream, the conversion is done from external (file buffer) to internal encoding by a function `do_in()` from the facet.
- when writing data to a stream, the conversion is done  from the internal data to the external (stored in the file) by a function `do_out()`.
- conversions can be between single byte or multi-byte encodings with or without a state (required if one of the encoding has variable length).

I've a very simple example converting between code page 850 format on file and iso8859-1 in memory.  Of course, you can adapt it to do the same thing for koi8r and CP1251.

The principle is the following:
[image]

As the character sets in my example are both defined for type `char`,  I've created my own one as follows:

```
class codecvt_cp850_iso8859 : public codecvt < char, char, mbstate_t > {
public:
    explicit codecvt_cp850_iso8859(size_t r=0) : codecvt(r) {}
protected:
    result do_in(mbstate_t &s, const char *from, const char *from_end, 
        const char*&from_next, 
        char *to, char*to_end, char*&to_next) const  // from cp850 to iso8859-1
    {
        result res=partial; 
        const char*p;
        for (p = from; p != from_end && to != to_end; p++)
            *to++ = ... /*  your stuff here, for example a conversion table */
        from_next = p;  // what's the next char to convert
        to_next = to;   // what's the next place to convert to
        if (p == from_end)
            res = p == from ? noconv : ok;
        return res; 
    }

    result do_out(mbstate_t &s, const char *from, const char *from_end, const char*&from_next,
        char *to, char*to_end, char*&to_next) const  // from iso8859-1 to cp850
    {
        result res = partial;
        const char*p;
        for (p = from; p != from_end && to != to_end; p++)
            *to++ = ... /* conversion in the other direction */ 
        from_next = p;  to_next = to;
        if (p == from_end)
                res = p == from ? noconv : ok;
        return res;
    }
    result do_unshift(mbstate_t &s, char*to, char*to_end, char*& to_next) const {
        to_next = to;    // Attention MSVC segfaults if this is missing ! 
        return ok;
    }
    int encoding() const {  return 1; } // fixed length for external representation
    bool do_always_noconv() const { return false; }
```

You can then use such code:

```
// read with conversion from cp850 in stream to iso in memory 
ifstream is850("test-cp850.txt");
is850.imbue(locale(is850.getloc(), new codecvt_cp850_iso8859 ())); // use our conversion
getline(is850, isotext); 
... 
// writing an iso string to a CP850 file: 
ofstream os850("test-cp850fromiso.txt");
os850.imbue(locale(os850.getloc(), new codecvt_cp850_iso8859()));
os850 << myisotext << endl;
...
```

Note that the standard library takes ownership on the codect provided and relases it when it's no longer needed.

## Application to strings

Finally, you can also use the codecvt to convert strings between the two formats in memory.

As the comment below shows, strings on their own have no locale.

So one way to do this is to use stringstreams.  Another approach is to use directly the [codecvt's functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/codecvt/) (`mycodecvt::in()`,  `mycodecvt::out()`  and `mycodecvt::length()` )

A last way is to use [`wstring_convert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/wstring_convert/).  But this one has the inconveneience of requiring a conversion with wide characters.

Comment: The question is about imbuing locales on _strings_ (which makes no sense at all), not streams.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit  you are of course right.  So i've completed the answer.  I've kept however the introduction with the behind codecvt, as I think it's is more difficult to apply without knowledge of its initial design purpose.